# In Liferay how to get the identity provider info and use them to programmatically trigger the SSO

Tags: java, authentication, single-sign-on, liferay, saml

I'm really new to Liferay and SSO and I have to do a very specific thing.
I am using Liferay DXP 7.4, so I have the Liferay SAML Connector 2.0 available.
In particular I need to configure Liferay as a Service Provider and add more than one Identity Provider Connection and I have done it through the UI.

It is absolutely not clear how to use the correct Identity Provider.
It doesn't seem there is something that automatically does it.

Since I have an Identity provider for each "friendlyurl", I guess I can use the groupId to identify a specific Identity Provider (setting the Identity provider name to a groupId).

Now in the custom login action implementation (a class that implements MVCActionCommand) what seems to miss is what I have commented in the following code:

```
@Override
protected void doProcessAction(ActionRequest actionRequest, ActionResponse actionResponse) throws Exception {
    ThemeDisplay themeDisplay = (ThemeDisplay) actionRequest.getAttribute(WebKeys.THEME_DISPLAY);
    HttpServletRequest request = PortalUtil.getOriginalServletRequest(PortalUtil.getHttpServletRequest(actionRequest));
    HttpServletResponse response = PortalUtil.getHttpServletResponse(actionResponse);

    long groupId = themeDisplay.getScopeGroupId();
    IdpConnection idpConnection = getIdpConfigByName(groupId); // <-- no idea 
    ....
    loginWithIdp(request, response, username, password, idpConnection); // <-- no idea
}
```

In this code I really don't know:

- if exists a class that maps the Idp connection (in the code I have called it "IdpConnection"),
- how to get idp info by name,
- how to use idp info to perform the login programmatically.

It is absolutely possible I am totally off track. So I will really appreciate any suggestion.

Comment: Why do you need to do this manually, when the infrastructure already takes care of this, e.g. when the portlet that this action belongs to is permission-protected, you can make sure that only users with the proper permissions (typically tied to being logged in) ever see (or send) this request.

Comment: Ok, so the question is: how to link an identity provider connection to a specific site/friendlyUrl/groupId in the configuration?
I don't think the framework checks with all the IdPs until it finds the one that returns an "ok" to the service provider.
I really think I am missing some details, even if I have read a lot of documentation.

Comment: In Liferay, a specific identity applies to the whole virtual instance, e.g. it spans the various sites that your portal holds. This means that there is no specific connection between a site and "its" identity provider: _All_ identity providers are available _for all_ sites. If you need them to be separated, you might rather look at virtual instances. This looks a lot like a [xy-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/364505), which is why I ask these additional questions.

Comment: Further, as you say "I have an identity provider for every friendly URL": How did you configure this? This is not part of Liferay's standard, so Liferay doesn't have an API to map from one to the other (that I know of). Also, with SSO, going the route of a "custom login action" sounds backwards to me. Please start with a description of _the underlying problem_ (in light of the x-y problem). Only then (and optionally), describe what you've done already (in the form of a [mcve])

Comment: "I have an identity provider for every friendly URL"
-> I gave a wrong explanation. I meant that this was the requirement. I am going to better detail everything in the next hours